# Nodejs : Depends: rlwrap but it is not installable

Tags: apt, node.js, ubuntu-14.04

Just bought a new fresh virtual server in the cloud, Ubuntu 14.04.

I updated my packages with apt-get update.

Got problems when trying to install node js. I followed this guide: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager

When I run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` I get this:

```
user@server sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: rlwrap but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is this rlwrap? I googled but did not find how to install it.

--**Update**--

I tried the suggestions below. No success. I downgraded to 12.04. Everything worked there.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same exact problem in Ubuntu 14.04. The solution:

1. Download `rlwrap` from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/rlwrap. 
   Here is a [Direct Link](http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rlwrap/rlwrap_0.34-2_amd64.deb)
2. Install it `sudo dpkg -i rlwrap_0.34-2_amd64.deb`
3. Install nodejs `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: Also worked for uninstallable liberror-perl while installing git :)

Answer (score 2):

1. enable universe repository `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"`
2. fix and update `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade`
3. try again (note that the node.js instructions replace the Ubuntu repositories with custom ones so be sure that script worked)

> ```
> >apt-cache show rlwrap
> Package: rlwrap
> Priority: optional
> Section: universe/editors
> Installed-Size: 300
> Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
> Original-Maintainer: Francois Marier <francois@debian.org>
> Architecture: amd64
> Version: 0.37-2
> Provides: readline-editor
> Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libncurses5 (>= 5.7+20100313), libreadline6 (>= 6.0)
> Filename: pool/universe/r/rlwrap/rlwrap_0.37-2_amd64.deb
> Size: 80968
> MD5sum: 8fca381b84e7205b92615d2d2f6df588
> SHA1: ea227d0b53c16cec64f259e349d69073fce972f8
> SHA256: 09d5d948a387f77a1f09b8ad800a73349dbcd6245f787496e0f1743df5259ea4
> Description-en: readline feature command line wrapper
>  This package provides a small utility that uses the GNU readline library
>  to allow the editing of keyboard input for any other command.  Input
>  history is remembered across invocations, separately for each command;
>  history completion and search work as in bash and completion word lists
>  can be specified on the command line.
> Homepage: http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/
> Description-md5: 2dd4e4df63ed824e61c4e21ad05cd1eb
> Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
> Origin: Ubuntu
> Task: edubuntu-desktop-kde, edubuntu-desktop-gnome
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me to install node.js on Ubuntu 14.04 and a bit of an explanation why I prefer to install node this way.
It involves adding a third party PPA - which has been used by many people and seems to be the most popular PPA for node on Ubuntu, run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

+

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

+

```
sudo apt-get update
```

+

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Check installation with

```
node -v
```

#### Background

It seems nodejs has a conflict with another package used by Debian and Ubuntu also called "node"

e.g. if you search Ubuntu repos with:

```
apt-cache search node | grep Amateur
```

You will see a package called

> node - Amateur Packet Radio Node program (transitional package)

Its an old ham radio package, which Debian/Ubuntu have given priority over nodejs in both the Ubuntu repos *and* as a command line argument.
I could be wrong but I believe Debain/Ubuntu may have modified their version of node to use the command `nodejs` where the normal command is `node`, in order to prevent conflicts between the 2 packages.
I don't ever plan to install the ham radio version so I choose to install a non-official version, which I know does respond to the command `node`, because I suspect the likelihood of breakages will be higher if other nodejs related programs try to make a call to `node` and don't get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever tries to install node on ubuntu vivid (ubuntu bq tablet): follow @bekce's solution, only you need to pay attention about the architecture of your machine. my tablet is `armhf`, so i downloaded `rlwrap` for `armhf` from:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rlwrap/0.41-1
```

and the remaining is the same:

```
sudo dpkg -i rlwrap_0.34-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```